# Gobblin Kafka to HDFS pull job error

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, gobblin

I'm trying to pull data from Kafka to HDFS using [Gobblin](https://github.com/linkedin/gobblin).

Gobblin version (compiled from github source code with command `sudo ./gradlew clean build -PuseHadoop2 -PhadoopVersion=2.7.1 -x test`):

```
0.6.2-546-g431188b
```

Hadoop version:

```
Hadoop 2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258
Subversion git@github.com:hortonworks/hadoop.git -r 13debf893a605e8a88df18a7d8d214f571e05289
Compiled by jenkins on 2016-04-24T16:02Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 2a2d95f05ec6c3ac547ed58cab713ac
This command was run using /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar
```

Gobblin job:

```
job.name=GobblinKafkaQuickStart
job.group=GobblinKafka
job.description=Gobblin quick start job for Kafka
job.lock.enabled=false
job.schedule=0 0/2 * * * ?

kafka.brokers=hd-mgt03:6667,hd-mgt02:6667,hd-mgt04:6667

source.class=gobblin.source.extractor.extract.kafka.KafkaSimpleSource
extract.namespace=gobblin.extract.kafka

writer.builder.class=gobblin.writer.AvroHdfsDataWriter
writer.file.path.type=tablename
writer.destination.type=HDFS
writer.output.format=AVRO

data.publisher.type=gobblin.publisher.BaseDataPublisher

mr.job.max.mappers=1

metrics.reporting.file.enabled=true
metrics.log.dir=/gobblin-kafka/metrics
metrics.reporting.file.suffix=txt

bootstrap.with.offset=earliest

fs.uri=hdfs://hdfs:8020
writer.fs.uri=hdfs://hdfs:8020
state.store.fs.uri=hdfs://hdfs:8020

mr.job.root.dir=/kafka/working
state.store.dir=/kafka/state-store
task.data.root.dir=/kafka/task-data
data.publisher.final.dir=/kafka/job-output
```

I'm trying to run `gobblin-mapreduce.sh` from `gobblin-dist/bin` folder, but getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main" gobblin.runtime.JobException: Job job_GobblinKafkaQuickStart_1464962113982 failed
    at gobblin.runtime.AbstractJobLauncher.launchJob(AbstractJobLauncher.java:363)
    at gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.CliMRJobLauncher.launchJob(CliMRJobLauncher.java:84)
    at gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.CliMRJobLauncher.run(CliMRJobLauncher.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.CliMRJobLauncher.main(CliMRJobLauncher.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Log file contains error:

```
2016-06-03 16:55:17 MSK ERROR [main] gobblin.runtime.AbstractJobLauncher  321 - Failed to launch and run job job_GobblinKafkaQuickStart_1464962113982: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_MR_AM_ADMIN_USER_ENV
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_MR_AM_ADMIN_USER_ENV
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.createApplicationSubmissionContext(YARNRunner.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.submitJob(YARNRunner.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.MRJobLauncher.runWorkUnits(MRJobLauncher.java:198)
    at gobblin.runtime.AbstractJobLauncher.launchJob(AbstractJobLauncher.java:296)
    at gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.CliMRJobLauncher.launchJob(CliMRJobLauncher.java:84)
    at gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.CliMRJobLauncher.run(CliMRJobLauncher.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.CliMRJobLauncher.main(CliMRJobLauncher.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

What could be the reason for this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From you error I can tell it might be the problem of JAR. 
Usually, this error (`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_MR_AM_ADMIN_USER_ENV`) is caused by jar conflicts. You can check your class path to see if there are any version conflicts.